# Shadow not showing on cell in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using UICollectionView to generate several thumbnails in a Master View.

This works fine and I am able to place a border around the cells as well as apply border (corner) radius.

The only thing that does not seem to stick is the shadow for each cell.

Here is my code

```
....

[cell.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:213.0/255.0f green:210.0/255.0f blue:199.0/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
[cell.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[cell.layer setCornerRadius:7.5f];
[cell.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[cell.layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[cell.layer setShadowRadius:8.0];
[cell.layer setShadowOpacity:0.8];

return cell;
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong and what I can do for the shadow to show?

Comment: Where are you setting the shadow? When you're init'ing the cell?

Comment: actually after initing the cell -- as you can see above, the code calling shadow is pretty much at the end of the code block

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to enable the shadow to be created outside of the bounds;

[cell.layer setMasksToBounds:NO];