# UICollectionViewCell Border / Shadow

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When building an iPad App, how can you draw a border around a UICollectionViewCell?

More details: I implemented a class ProductCell which extends UICollectionViewCell. Now, I would like to assign some fancy details, e.g. a border, shadow, etc. However, when trying to use something like [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874684/shadow-not-showing-on-cell-in-ios), Xcode tells me that the receiver type 'CALayer' is a forward declaration.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just for a bit more implementation:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

in your.m

Make sure your class implements

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

as this is where the cell is setup.

You can then change `cell.layer.background` (only available once quartz is imported)

See below

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"pressieCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    //other cell setup here

    cell.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor=[UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

## Swift

*Updated for Swift 3*

Assuming you have your [Collection View set up with the required methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31735229/3681880), you can just write a few lines of code to add the border.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan 
    
    // add a border
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // optional
    
    return cell
}
```

**Notes**

- It is not necessary to import `QuartzCore` in Swift if you have already imported `UIKit`.
- If you also want to add shadow, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34984063/3681880).

Answer (score 7):

You need to include the framework `QuartzCore` and import the header into your class:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**

```
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

Add it in datasource method, after creating the cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
     cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
     cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to  **add this config into your custom cell implementation**, not in datasource delegate method.

```
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.layer.cornerRadius = 8 // optional
```